# 530, b'5.7.0 Authentication Required Error when using gmail to send emails through django

Tags: python, django, email, smtp, gmail

Im having problems with sending emails through gmail in Django. I have set up a app password and yet I cant seem to send emails through Django. My settings.py look like this

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_FROM_USER = 'ianis.donica@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'my app password'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_USE_SSL = False
```

To my best of knowledge it isn't a gmail specific issue, as I had experienced the same problems across yahoo mail and Sendgrid, the function that's responsible for sending the email looks like this

```
def send_activation_email(user, request):
    current_site = get_current_site(request)
    email_subject = "Activation Email"
    context = {"user": user, 
                "domain": current_site,
                'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)), 
                'token': generate_token.make_token(user)
                }
    email_body = render_to_string('email/activate.html',context)

    email = EmailMessage(subject=email_subject, body=email_body, from_email=settings.EMAIL_FROM_USER, to=[user.email])

    email.send()
```

and the full error message is this

```
SMTPSenderRefused at /register/

(530, b'5.7.0 Authentication Required. Learn more at\n5.7.0  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError g9-20020a170906394900b00872a726783dsm9975622eje.217 - gsmtp', 'ianis.donica@gmail.com')
```

What I tried was changing to yahoo and SendGrid mail but the same issues occurred there, just with different names.  I also tried changing some details but that shouldn't be the problem? Yet I cant seem to send an email anywhere. If anyone can help me I would really appreciate it

I also have IMAP enabled

Comment: Please edit your code and include  your EmailMessage method

Comment: it's a method from django from django.core.mail called [EmailMessage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/email/#s-the-emailmessage-class), the first part of the code is in the settings.py and the second one is in the views.py that is getting called as soon as the new user is created in the database, [here](https://pastebin.com/0fzANq9Q) is the full views.py if needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with me using EMAIL_FROM_USER instead of EMAIL_HOST_USER, so I would need to change the code to this

`settings.py`

```
...
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'ianis.donica@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'my app password'
...
```

`views.py`

```
...
email = EmailMessage(subject=email_subject, body=email_body, from_email=settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, to=[user.email])
...
```

This is because without EMAIL_HOST_USER, Django won't try to authenticate